# WPF ContextMenuOpening event not firing when TextBox has .Text

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a user control ultimately derived from a TextBox.

I want to suppress the right-click context menu for this control.

I've added a code to intercept the ContextMenuOpening event on the user control and to suppress the context menu:

```
ContextMenuOpening +=  HandleIt;
...
private void HandleIt(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

When the control is empty (no .Text) this works fine.

However, when the control has some text, HandleIt() is not even called.

Am I doing something wrong?

How do I suppress the context menu for this user control under all conditions?

Comment: How can "a user control be ultimately derived from a TextBox"?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I suppress the context menu for this user control under all conditions?

C#:

```
ContextMenu = null;
```

or Xaml:

```
<TextBox ContextMenu="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: That does completely suppress the context menu (thank you) but doesn't explain why the ContextMenuOpening event on the control derived from a TextBox doesn't fire when the control has .Text.

Comment: @MikeZ In some situations setting `ContextMenu` to `null` doesn't work. Try using `ContextMenu = new ContextMenu { Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed };` Don't know about event problem, I should test it.